# Improving complete sql query in stored proc

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have a stored proc that is used to populate a dashboard like grid in WPF.  I've refined the query over time, and to be honest, the performance could be better.  I'm at the point now that I do not know any good ways to improve the query where I can gain performance with the time it takes to execute.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Below is the stored proc:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetDashboardMainNew]
    AS
         BEGIN
             SET NOCOUNT ON;
             SELECT JC.job_number AS SalesOrder,
                    dbo.cust.Company AS Customer,
                    JC.Plan_ship_date AS PlannedShipDate,
                    JC.latest_ship_date AS LatestShipDate,
                    JC.planned_fab_complete AS PlanFabComplete,
                    JC.fldPromisedDate AS CommittedShipDate,
                    JC.Materials_of_Construction AS MatofCons,
                    JC.Fab_rating AS FabRating,
                    JC.ass_rating AS [Assembly Rating],
                    JC.shipped AS OpenShipped,
                    JC.electrical_status,
                    JC.dp_credit_status,
                    JC.fldCustRequestDate,
                    JC.commercial_terms,
                    JC.Approved_by,
                    fldLiquidatedDamages,
                    fldLiquidatedDamagesDesc,
                    CASE
                        WHEN hot_list = '0'
                             OR hot_list = 'No'
                        THEN 'No'
                        ELSE 'Yes'
                    END AS HotList,
                    CASE
                        WHEN JC.latest_ship_date IS NOT NULL
                             AND JC.fldPromisedDate IS NULL
                        THEN JC.latest_ship_date
                        ELSE JC.fldPromisedDate
                    END AS CommitDate,
                    CASE
                        WHEN dp_credit_status = 1
                             AND commercial_terms = 'Complete'
                        THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END AS TermsMet,
                    CASE
                        WHEN JC.fldPromisedDate IS NULL
                        THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END AS SortByDate,
                    dbo.tblShippingInfo.fldShipmentRequestID,
                    CASE
                        WHEN JC.fleInspectionType <> 'None'
                        THEN JC.fleInspectionType
                        ELSE NULL
                    END AS InspectionType,
                    JC.fldInspectionNotes,
                 JC.DueDateExtraTime,
                    CASE
                        WHEN JC.fleInspectionType <> 'None'
                             AND JC.fleInspectionType IS NOT NULL
                        THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END AS InspectionDesc,
                    advanced_buying,
                    SortedOrder,
                    SalesOrderStatusGroup,
                    SalesOrderStatus,
                    SpecialOpList,
                    OperationDueBy,
                    test,
                    wpStatus,
                    SpecialOpsCount,
                    InChangeOrder,
                    RequiresSpecialPaint
             FROM dbo.cust
                  INNER JOIN dbo.Job_Control JC ON dbo.cust.CUST# = JC.Cust#
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblShippingInfo ON JC.job_number = dbo.tblShippingInfo.fldJobNumberID
                  OUTER APPLY
             (
                 SELECT dbo.udfGetManStatusFullSortOrder(JC.job_number) AS SortedOrder
             ) acolumn
                  OUTER APPLY
             (
                 SELECT ISNULL(dbo.udfGetManStatusBySOGroupNo(JC.job_number, 1), dbo.udfGetManStatusNew(JC.job_number)) AS SalesOrderStatusGroup
             ) bcolumn
                  OUTER APPLY
             (
                 SELECT ISNULL(dbo.udfGetManStatusBySOGroupNo(JC.job_number, 1), dbo.udfGetManStatusNew(JC.job_number)) AS SalesOrderStatus
             ) ccolumn
                  OUTER APPLY
             (
                 SELECT dbo.udfGetSpecialOperations(JC.job_number) AS SpecialOpList
             ) dcolumn
                  OUTER APPLY
             (
                 SELECT CASE
                            WHEN dbo.udfGetManStatusNew(JC.job_number) LIKE '%Approval%' OR dbo.udfGetManStatusNew(JC.job_number) LIKE '%Re-Approval%'
                            THEN JC.Approval_Due
                            ELSE dbo.udfGetDueByPerOperation(JC.job_number, 1)
                        END AS OperationDueBy
             ) ecolumn
                  OUTER APPLY
             (
                 SELECT dbo.udfGetGroupCount(JC.job_number) AS test
             ) fcolumn
                  OUTER APPLY
             (
                 SELECT dbo.udfGetOpenWorkPackagesByDesigner(JC.job_number) AS wpStatus
             ) gcolumn
                  OUTER APPLY
             (
                 SELECT dbo.udfGetSpecialOpsCount(JC.job_number) AS SpecialOpsCount
             ) hcolumn
                  OUTER APPLY
             (
                 SELECT dbo.udfIsActiveChangeOrder(JC.job_number) AS InChangeOrder
             ) icolumn
                  OUTER APPLY
             (
                 SELECT dbo.udfRequiresSpecialColor(JC.job_number) AS RequiresSpecialPaint
             ) jcolumn
             WHERE(JC.shipped = 'Open')
                  OR (JC.shipped = 'Hold');
         END;
```

Below are the outter apply functions that are called:

```
        ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetManStatusFullSortOrder] 
    (
        @SalesOrderNumber int
    )
    RETURNS INT
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @shipped nvarchar(50);
        DECLARE @eng_complete datetime;
        DECLARE @Drawing_Info nvarchar(50);
        DECLARE @Release_to_engineering datetime;
        DECLARE @Dwg_Sent datetime;
        DECLARE @Approval_done datetime;
        DECLARE @Detail bit;
        DECLARE @Release_to_shop datetime;
        DECLARE @OperationCount int;
        DECLARE @SortOrder INT;
        DECLARE @p as INT = 1;
        DECLARE @NonOpSortOrder INT;

        SET @NonOpSortOrder = dbo.udfIsOnHoldSort(@SalesOrderNumber)

        IF @NonOpSortOrder > 0 
            RETURN @nonopsortorder

            SELECT @SortOrder = (SELECT TOP(@p) dbo.ShopRouting.DashboardSortOrder
                FROM    dbo.Product INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ProductMfgGrouping ON dbo.Product.Record_no = dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.Record_no INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MfgGrouping ON dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.GroupOperations ON dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.GroupOperations.MfgGroupingID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ShopRouting ON dbo.GroupOperations.ShopRoutingID = dbo.ShopRouting.ShopRoutingID
                WHERE  (dbo.Product.Job_number = @SalesOrderNumber) AND (dbo.MfgGrouping.GroupingNumber = 1) AND (dbo.GroupOperations.Completed IS NULL)
                GROUP BY dbo.ShopRouting.Description, dbo.GroupOperations.NewSortOrder, dbo.ShopRouting.DashboardSortOrder
                ORDER BY dbo.GroupOperations.NewSortOrder);

        IF @SortOrder IS NOT NULL
                RETURN @SortOrder

        SELECT
            @shipped = shipped,
            @eng_complete = eng_complete,
            @Drawing_Info = Drawing_Info,
            @Release_to_engineering = Release_to_engineering,
            @Dwg_Sent = Dwg_Sent,
            @Approval_done = Approval_done,
            @Detail = Detail,
            @Release_to_shop = Release_to_shop

        FROM
            job_control

        WHERE
            job_number = @SalesOrderNumber

        BEGIN
            SET @OperationCount = flex2ksql.dbo.udfGetGroupOperationsCount(@SalesOrderNumber);
        END

        IF (@shipped = 'Hold')
            RETURN 33

        IF (@eng_complete IS NULL)
            BEGIN
                 IF (@Release_to_engineering IS NULL)

                    RETURN 32

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Approval' AND
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Dwg_Sent IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Approval_done IS NULL)

                    RETURN 28

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Re-Approval' AND
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Dwg_Sent IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Approval_done IS NULL)

                    RETURN 29

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Approval' AND
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Dwg_Sent IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Detail = 1 AND
                    @Approval_done IS NOT NULL)

                    If (@OperationCount) = 0 OR (@OperationCount IS NULL)
                        RETURN 27
                    ELSE
                        RETURN 26

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Approval' AND 
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL)

                    RETURN 30

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Re-Approval' AND
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Dwg_Sent IS NULL AND
                    @Approval_done IS NULL)

                    RETURN 31

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Certified' AND
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Detail = 1)

                    If (@OperationCount) = 0 OR (@OperationCount IS NULL)
                        RETURN 27
                    ELSE
                        RETURN 26

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'No Drawing Required' AND
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL)

                    If (@OperationCount) = 0 OR (@OperationCount IS NULL)
                        RETURN 27
                    ELSE
                        RETURN 26

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Certified')

                    If (@OperationCount) = 0 OR (@OperationCount IS NULL)
                        RETURN 27
                    ELSE
                        RETURN 26

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Sales Drawing' AND
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Release_to_shop IS NOT NULL)

                    If (@OperationCount) = 0 OR (@OperationCount IS NULL)
                        RETURN 27
                    ELSE
                        RETURN 26
                ELSE
                    RETURN 27

            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                RETURN 27
            END
        RETURN 99



        ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetManStatusBySOGroupNo] 
    (
        @SalesOrder int, @GroupNo int
    )
    RETURNS varchar(100)
    AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @ManStatus varchar(100);
        DECLARE @p as INT = 1;
        DECLARE @NonOpSortOrder INT;

        SET @NonOpSortOrder = dbo.udfIsOnHoldSort(@SalesOrder)

        IF @NonOpSortOrder > 0 
            RETURN 'Hold'
        ELSE

                SELECT @ManStatus = (SELECT TOP(@p) dbo.ShopRouting.Description
                FROM dbo.Product INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ProductMfgGrouping ON dbo.Product.Record_no = dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.Record_no INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MfgGrouping ON dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.GroupOperations ON dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.GroupOperations.MfgGroupingID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ShopRouting ON dbo.GroupOperations.ShopRoutingID = dbo.ShopRouting.ShopRoutingID
                WHERE  (dbo.Product.Job_number = @SalesOrder) AND (dbo.MfgGrouping.GroupingNumber = @GroupNo) AND (dbo.GroupOperations.Completed is null)
                GROUP BY dbo.ShopRouting.Description, dbo.Product.Model_NO, dbo.GroupOperations.NewSortOrder
                ORDER BY dbo.GroupOperations.NewSortOrder);

                RETURN @ManStatus


        ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetManStatusNew] 
    (
        @SalesOrderNumber int
    )
    RETURNS nvarchar(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @shipped nvarchar(50);
        DECLARE @eng_complete datetime;
        DECLARE @Drawing_Info nvarchar(50);
        DECLARE @Release_to_engineering datetime;
        DECLARE @Dwg_Sent datetime;
        DECLARE @Approval_done datetime;
        DECLARE @Detail bit;
        DECLARE @Release_to_shop datetime;
        DECLARE @OperationCount int;

        SELECT
            @shipped = shipped,
            @eng_complete = eng_complete,
            @Drawing_Info = Drawing_Info,
            @Release_to_engineering = Release_to_engineering,
            @Dwg_Sent = Dwg_Sent,
            @Approval_done = Approval_done,
            @Detail = Detail,
            @Release_to_shop = Release_to_shop

        FROM
            job_control

        WHERE
            job_number = @SalesOrderNumber

        BEGIN
            SET @OperationCount = flex2ksql.dbo.udfGetGroupOperationsCount(@SalesOrderNumber);
        END

        IF (@shipped = 'Hold')
            RETURN 'Hold'

        IF (@eng_complete IS NULL)
            BEGIN
              IF (@Release_to_engineering IS NULL)

                    RETURN 'Not Released'

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Approval' AND
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Dwg_Sent IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Approval_done IS NULL)

                    RETURN 'Approval Out'

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Re-Approval' AND
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Dwg_Sent IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Approval_done IS NULL)

                    RETURN 'Re-Approval Out'

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Approval' AND
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Dwg_Sent IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Detail = 1 AND
                    @Approval_done IS NOT NULL)

                    If (@OperationCount) = 0 OR (@OperationCount IS NULL)
                        RETURN 'Routing'
                    ELSE
                        RETURN 'Detail'

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Approval' AND 
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL)

                    RETURN 'Approval To Be Done'

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Re-Approval' AND
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Dwg_Sent IS NULL AND
                    @Approval_done IS NULL)

                    RETURN 'Re-Approval To Be Done'
                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Certified' AND
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Detail = 1)

                    If (@OperationCount) = 0 OR (@OperationCount IS NULL)
                        RETURN 'Routing'
                    ELSE
                        RETURN 'Detail'

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'No Drawing Required' AND
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL)

                    If (@OperationCount) = 0 OR (@OperationCount IS NULL)
                        RETURN 'Routing'
                    ELSE
                        RETURN 'Detail'

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Certified')

                    If (@OperationCount) = 0 OR (@OperationCount IS NULL)
                        RETURN 'Routing'
                    ELSE
                        RETURN 'Detail'

                IF (@Drawing_Info = 'Sales Drawing' AND
                    @Release_to_engineering IS NOT NULL AND
                    @Release_to_shop IS NOT NULL)

                    If (@OperationCount) = 0 OR (@OperationCount IS NULL)
                        RETURN 'Routing'
                    ELSE
                        RETURN 'Detail'
                ELSE
                    RETURN 'Routing'

            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                RETURN 'Routing'
            END
        RETURN NULL


ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetSpecialOperations] 
(
@SalesOrder int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN   
DECLARE @returnVal nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT @returnVal = Stuff((SELECT N', ' + dbo.ShopRouting.Description FROM dbo.Product INNER JOIN
        dbo.ProductMfgGrouping ON dbo.Product.Record_no = dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.Record_no INNER JOIN
        dbo.MfgGrouping ON dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID INNER JOIN
        dbo.GroupOperations ON dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.GroupOperations.MfgGroupingID INNER JOIN
        dbo.ShopRouting ON dbo.GroupOperations.ShopRoutingID = dbo.ShopRouting.ShopRoutingID                         
    WHERE (dbo.ShopRouting.Standard = 0) AND (dbo.Product.Job_number = @SalesOrder)
    GROUP BY dbo.ShopRouting.Description, dbo.ShopRouting.DashboardSortOrder
    ORDER BY dbo.ShopRouting.DashboardSortOrder DESC 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'')

RETURN @returnVal


        ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetDueByPerOperation] 
    (
        @SalesOrder int, @GroupNo int
    )
    RETURNS varchar(100)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ManStatus varchar(100);
        DECLARE @p as INT = 1;

        SELECT @ManStatus = (SELECT TOP(@p) dbo.GroupOperations.StartBy
    FROM     dbo.Product INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ProductMfgGrouping ON dbo.Product.Record_no = dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.Record_no INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MfgGrouping ON dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.GroupOperations ON dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.GroupOperations.MfgGroupingID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ShopRouting ON dbo.GroupOperations.ShopRoutingID = dbo.ShopRouting.ShopRoutingID
    WHERE  (dbo.Product.Job_number = @SalesOrder) AND (dbo.MfgGrouping.GroupingNumber = @GroupNo) AND (dbo.GroupOperations.Completed IS NULL) AND (dbo.GroupOperations.Active = 0)
    GROUP BY dbo.ShopRouting.[Description], dbo.Product.Model_NO, dbo.GroupOperations.NewSortOrder, dbo.GroupOperations.StartBy
    ORDER BY dbo.GroupOperations.NewSortOrder);

        RETURN @ManStatus


        ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetGroupCount] 
    (
        @SalesOrder int
    )
    RETURNS varchar(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @result varchar(MAX)
        DECLARE @result2 varchar(MAX)

    SET @result = ''

    SELECT @result = @result + Description + ': ' + Cast(StatusCount as varchar(5)) + ', ' FROM vwLineItemGroupStatusCounts WHERE Job_number = @SalesOrder
    ORDER BY vwLineItemGroupStatusCounts.NewSortOrder

    SELECT @result2 = substring(@result, 0, len(@result)) --trim extra "," at end

        -- Return the result of the function
        RETURN @result2


        ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetOpenWorkPackagesByDesigner] 
    (
        @SalesOrder int
    )
    RETURNS varchar(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @result varchar(MAX)
        DECLARE @result2 varchar(MAX)

    SET @result = ''

    --SELECT @result = @result + Fldusername + ': ' + Cast(StatusCount as varchar(5)) + ', ' FROM vwOpenWorkPackagesByDesigner WHERE Job_number = @SalesOrder
    SELECT @result = @result + eng_difficulty_category + ' ' FROM vwOpenWorkPackagesEngRating WHERE job_number = @SalesOrder
    SELECT @result = @result + Fldusername + ' ' + Cast(coalesce(fldPriority,'none') as varchar(5)) + ' ' + cast(PercentComplete as varchar(10)) + '% ' + fldTaskCategoryAbbr + '; ' FROM vwOpenWorkPackagesByDesigner WHERE fldSalesOrder = @SalesOrder

    SELECT @result2 = substring(@result, 0, len(@result)) --trim extra "," at end

        -- Return the result of the function
        RETURN @result2


        ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetSpecialOpsCount] 
    (
        @SalesOrder int
    )
    RETURNS int
    AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @returnVal int;

        SELECT @returnVal = COUNT(dbo.GroupOperations.GroupOperationID)
    FROM     dbo.Product INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ProductMfgGrouping ON dbo.Product.Record_no = dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.Record_no INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MfgGrouping ON dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.GroupOperations ON dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.GroupOperations.MfgGroupingID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ShopRouting ON dbo.GroupOperations.ShopRoutingID = dbo.ShopRouting.ShopRoutingID
    WHERE  (dbo.ShopRouting.Standard = 0) AND (dbo.Product.Job_number = @SalesOrder) AND (dbo.ShopRouting.ShopRoutingID NOT IN (15,16))

        If (@returnVal) = 0 OR (@returnVal IS NULL)
            SET @returnVal = 0;
        Return @returnVal;


        ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfIsActiveChangeOrder] (@SalesOrder numeric(18, 0))

    RETURNS Bit

    AS

    BEGIN

        DECLARE @isCO Bit
        DECLARE @SOFound as numeric(18)

        SET @SOFound = 0

            BEGIN
            SELECT
                @SOFound = fldSalesOrder        
            FROM
                [flex2kSQL].[dbo].[vwChangeOrdersAllActive]
            WHERE
                fldSalesOrder = @SalesOrder
            END


            if @SOFound =0
                SET @isCO=0
            else
                SET @isCO=1


        RETURN @isCO


        ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfRequiresSpecialColor] 
    (
        @SalesOrder INT
    )
    RETURNS INT
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ReturnVal int;

        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.MfgGrouping INNER JOIN
                dbo.ProductMfgGrouping ON dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID INNER JOIN
                dbo.Product ON dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.Record_no = dbo.Product.Record_no INNER JOIN
                dbo.GroupOperations ON dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.GroupOperations.MfgGroupingID
            WHERE (dbo.Product.Job_number = @SalesOrder) AND (dbo.GroupOperations.ShopRoutingID IN (23, 24, 25)))
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnVal = 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnVal = 0
        END

        Return @ReturnVal;
```

Below is a row of sample data from executing the stored proc (removed every row but test order):

> SalesOrder Customer    PlannedShipDate LatestShipDate  PlanFabComplete CommittedShipDate   MatofCons   FabRating   Assembly Rating OpenShipped electrical_status   dp_credit_status    fldCustRequestDate  commercial_terms    Approved_by fldLiquidatedDamages    fldLiquidatedDamagesDesc    HotList CommitDate  TermsMet    SortByDate  fldShipmentRequestID    InspectionType  fldInspectionNotes  DueDateExtraTime    InspectionDesc  advanced_buying SortedOrder SalesOrderStatusGroup   SalesOrderStatus    SpecialOpList   OperationDueBy  test    wpStatus    SpecialOpsCount InChangeOrder   RequiresSpecialPaint
>   76506   Test Customer   6/16/2020   12/31/2020  NULL    11/28/2016  SS  C   C   Open    In Test 0   9/29/2016   NULL    Premount/Prewire    0   NULL    Yes 11/28/2016  0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    7   0   Complete    26  Detail  Detail  NULL    6/2/2020    Detail: 6   NULL    0   0   0

[image]
Lastly, below is a screen shot showing how the data is displayed and organized on the main form.

[image]

**--EDIT--**
Latest query execution plan after changing functions called to inline table functions.
[Latest Query Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1A0p89mf)

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan? Can you [share](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) it?

Comment: @HoneyBadger please see the following link for the actual execution plan: [BrentOzarPasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJmdsmW7G)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query optimisation is more of an art form than a science.

What stands out is that many of the functions you've employed are written in an imperative style. As a starting point, I would investigate whether the OUTER APPLYs against function calls can be rewritten as LEFT JOINs against views (either written inline, if the functions are unique to this report, or against a pre-defined view).

So for example, the function `udfRequiresSpecialColor` can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT
    dbo.Product.Job_number

FROM 
    dbo.MfgGrouping 

INNER JOIN
    dbo.ProductMfgGrouping 
    ON dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID 

INNER JOIN
    dbo.Product 
    ON dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.Record_no = dbo.Product.Record_no 

INNER JOIN 
    dbo.GroupOperations 
    ON dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.GroupOperations.MfgGroupingID
    AND (dbo.GroupOperations.ShopRoutingID IN (23, 24, 25))
```

This returns a single table containing *all* `Job_number`s that require a special colour, which can be joined against.

Then, in the main query, the following OUTER APPLY is replaced:

```
SELECT
    ...
    RequiresSpecialPaint
    ...
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT dbo.udfRequiresSpecialColor(JC.job_number) AS RequiresSpecialPaint
) AS jcolumn
```

...and is replaced with a LEFT JOIN in the main query:

```
SELECT
    ...
    IIF(jobs_requiring_special_paint.job_number IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS RequiresSpecialPaint
    ...

LEFT JOIN
    (
        [here you can either a call to the new udfRequiresSpecialColor defined as a database view or an inlinable function, or simply include the code above as a subquery]
    ) AS jobs_requiring_special_paint
    ON (JC.job_number = jobs_requiring_special_paint.job_number)
```

By left-joining onto this table, there will be a job_number for those jobs that have special paint, and a NULL value for those jobs that don't - that is then converted to a 0/1 flag in the select statement, rather than being part of the sub-function.

You get the general picture, and you can see that the entire part of the query that deals with getting the special paint data, is now dealt with in a purely set-based fashion.

Removing imperative code gives the query optimiser more latitude to analyse and reorganise the query in a way that executes more efficiently but preserves the logic you've defined.

You may also find ultimately that what are currently a variety of separate OUTER APPLY queries can be condensed into a single common definition (or fewer common definitions) of the relevant table relationships, with the necessary filtering applied in the ON clause.

For example, `udfGetDueByPerOperation` seems to hit the same tables as `udfRequiresSpecialColor` (those tables being `MfgGrouping, ProductMfgGrouping, Product, GroupOperations`), and in the same basic relationships (INNER JOINs on the same keys), but with `ShopRouting` tacked on the end.

It might therefore be possible to define common code (either as a database view or inline function, or as a common table expression/WITH clause), and the filtering implemented in the final JOIN clauses against the common table. This is likely to make the code far shorter and easier to understand and maintain, and again it possibly helps the query engine optimise its plan. I can talk more about how this approach would be applied if required.

I note that there are some functions, such as `udfGetManStatusNew`, that have relatively complex decision logic, which might be difficult to reduce to an expression-based calculation whilst retaining clarity and correctness.

Again though, even as a partial solution without completely eliminating imperative code from the function, it is likely to be far more efficient if such a function is rewritten in such a way that it is given a *table* of all job_numbers, hitting the `job_control` table once for the details of all relevant jobs, using an OUTER APPLY to hit the `udfGetGroupOperationsCount` function for each job (or using the techniques described above to reduce the OUTER APPLY to a LEFT JOIN) and capturing `@OperationCount` as an additional column (instead of assigning to a scalar variable). Then, once the 'ingredients' of the function have been gathered in into a single table this way, *then* iterate through the imperative code to derive the necessary calculations for the status of each job).

I don't want to pre-judge the results that you will get from this general approach, because query engines can be unpredictable, but my suspicion is that it should improve performance, if it can be improved.

It might also help if you can get an idea of which parts of the query are contributing most to its poor performance - assuming it is not uniformly slow.

If you need any more guidance, ask away. Let me know also if you have any joy with this.

**EDIT:**
Further information, based on comments below.

I've just realised that I was misinterpreting the query plan that you posted - because the functions are imperative, it doesn't show the query plan for them, and does not include their cost. If you rewrite them as inlinable functions, post another query plan, which will start to show the query plan and the full cost of the functions themselves (at the moment they appear on the query plan as low-cost constant scans, with no further plan information).

The difference between an imperative/multi-statement function, and an inlinable function looks like this (note to avoid confusion, I have a DUAL table in SQL Server, to mirror the Oracle functionality which is built-in by default):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fxn_imperative] 
(   
     @dummy     VARCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnVal int;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE DUMMY = @dummy)
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnVal = 1
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnVal = 0
        END

    Return @ReturnVal;
END
-- called like so: SELECT dbo.fxn_imperative('X') AS dummy_exists;


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fxn_inline] 
(   
     @dummy     VARCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT ISNULL( (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE DUMMY = @dummy), 0) AS dummy_exists
)
-- called like so: SELECT * FROM fxn_inline('X');
```

These functions are more or less equivalent in functionality - but only the inline one will appear on the query plan for the query which calls the function.

Regards the LEFT JOIN approach, you don't define the inner query as a function in that case - you define it as a view (or simply write it inline as a subquery) and join onto it (using the job_number as the join condition, as the replacement for the parameter that would have been passed to the original function). I've already shown roughly how that approach is applied above as part of my original post.

If I wanted to go with the grain of how your existing query is approaching things (in terms of calls to functions which are OUTER APPLYed), I'd define the function as follows (I'm assuming the underlying query for special paint only ever returns a single row per job/salesorder):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfRequiresSpecialColor2] 
(   
     @SalesOrder INT
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

    WITH special_paint_subquery AS
    (
        SELECT
            dbo.Product.Job_number

        FROM 
            dbo.MfgGrouping 

        INNER JOIN
            dbo.ProductMfgGrouping 
            ON dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID 

        INNER JOIN
            dbo.Product 
            ON dbo.ProductMfgGrouping.Record_no = dbo.Product.Record_no 

        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.GroupOperations 
            ON dbo.MfgGrouping.MfgGroupingID = dbo.GroupOperations.MfgGroupingID
            AND (dbo.GroupOperations.ShopRoutingID IN (23, 24, 25))

    )

    SELECT ISNULL( (SELECT 1 FROM special_paint_subquery WHERE dbo.Product.Job_number = @SalesOrder), 0) AS requires_special_paint
)
```

If the function is written this way, the plan for the function will show up if you get a plan for the main query.

The function is called in the same way you currently call udfRequiresSpecialColor - by cross applying it with the job_number passed as a parameter.

Once you have defined the function in this way, actually converting the function call to a left join becomes trivial (the `WITH special_paint_subquery ...` part goes into the view definition, the `WHERE dbo.Product.Job_number = @SalesOrder` goes into the join condition in the main query, and the SELECT statement of the main query is modified to translate a NULL match into a zero as I originally illustrated).

Comment: Steve - thank you very much for the detailed comment and helpful tips. Originally I used left joins, and over time have continuously tweaked the query in this stored proc. I have been able to get it down to 3 seconds to execute, down from ~20 seconds. We did some database server tweaking with paging, etc, and now it is back up to ~17 seconds. I will definitely give your recommendations a try. I'm determined to get this query as efficient as possible. And yes, I do find 'joy' in this :) Lastly, if you could talk more about the approach with CTE/WITH clause, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: @outdoorsman33, just to be clear, "tell me if you have any joy" is idiomatic English for "tell me if it works"! Looking at the query plan you've posted above, I would say almost all the pain is being experienced between Job_control and Cust. I assume the Cust table has a sensible number of rows - how big is the Job_control table?

Comment: @outdoorsman33, regards the CTE/WITH clause, you may well find that many of the functions can be satisfied by hitting the base tables once for all necessary rows (i.e. the subset of rows that relate to the job_number), and then all functions are basically just various manipulations or aggregations of this subset of rows - which should be fast for any reasonable number of rows. But looking at your query plan now, it's not obvious that it is even the functions which are contributing the most weight to this query.

Comment: Also, finally, you say the query was originally written with left joins to perform all the work that the functions now do? If so, why did you rewrite them into imperative, row-by-row form? Was there an appreciable performance improvement?

Comment: Steve - thanks for the 'tell me if it works' explanation ;)
The CUST table has 102,976 rows. Job_Control has 10,516 rows. Please keep in mind that I played no role in the original table design of these tables, which has been somewhat the challenge in creating optimal queries.

Comment: Steve - over time - two plus years - I have tried to improve this query. As you can tell, it's doing a lot to retrieve data from all over. To be honest, I don't know if there was an appreciable performance improvement between using the left joins and row-by-row current version. Honestly, where I want to end up, is where you have mentioned in your second to last comment. I'm looking to achieve where my functions hit a base table once, I just haven't figured out how to exactly achieve this.

Comment: Steve - I think I'm on the right track here. I created an inline function for udfIsActiveChangeOrger and udfRequiresSpecialColor. I then LEFT JOIN on these ITVs.
IIF(ChangeOrder.fldSalesOrder IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS InChangeOrder, IIF(jobs_requiring_special_paint.job_number IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS RequiresSpecialPaint..
LEFT JOIN (SELECT fldSalesOrder FROM udfIsActiveChangeOrder2()) AS ChangeOrder ON (JC.job_number = ChangeOrder.fldSalesOrder) LEFT JOIN (SELECT Job_number FROM udfRequiresSpecialColor2()) AS jobs_requiring_special_paint ON (JC.job_number = jobs_requiring_special_paint.job_number)

Comment: Steve - thank you so much! I cannot explain how much of a help you are being! I'm familiar with each separate technique but putting it "all together" as you have kindly shown, has really helped me to understand how to better define this query. Let me digest all of this, and once implemented, I'll edit my post as well as include an updated execution plan. Again, thanks so much Steve!

Comment: Steve - i've edited my post above to include the latest execution plan at the end of the post. I've changed all of the called functions to inline functions per your suggestion. The query now executes ~1-2 seconds; which is great! I very much appreciate all of your help on this! If there are any glaring issues from the execution plan, and you feel like sharing, please let me know. Again, many thanks Steve!

Comment: @outdoorsman33, glad to hear that performance has improved! To be honest the query plan is now so large that I struggled to review it, and I would suggest that if we're down to 1-2 seconds, we probably won't get much more improvement. Just one last thing though, don't forget to up-vote and mark my answer as "answered"! :)